# Unity3d off map object updates

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a world, its 100x100 tiles. I've got a viewport thats 10x10 tiles. I also have a cow that walks around the world. This cow is a GameObject with a script on it that make it move around.

How do I make it go about walking around a world when its not visible in the current viewport. It's GameObject would be non-active and so would all the tile GameObjects for the portion of the world not in view.

Comment: Depends on how you are making it move. GameObjects don't deactivate when they leave the viewport, animations can be deactivated, but the GameObjects themselves and their attached scripts don't unless you explicitly told it to.

Comment: Here's something that might help you: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

Comment: Hi @JoeBlow, well nothing really answered the question. I'll try to expand more. But in general I *have* to deactivate tiles outside the 10x10 area around the player. Unity doesn't much like when there are 10,000 active GameObjects, even when there are no scripts running on those GameObjects.